# VS2022 after adding a new cpp unit to cmake project and configuring cache, how to avoid recomiling all cpp units when build all

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022

After adding a new cpp file and in order to get it to join in project, I must click project -> configure cache. Then I click build -> build all, the whole project, all cpp units get recompiled. I can't tolerate.
vs2019 has expected behavior that only adding cpp unit gets compiled.
After I update to vs2022, everything becomes terrible, whole cpp files get recompiled from one by one.

using follow statement in my CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE LIB_SRC "*.cpp")
add_library(lib ${LIB_SRC})
```

Comment: Do you get the same if you just build the project? You shouldn't need to rebuild the cache normally

Comment: I found that this problem is related to pch. After I disabled pch target_precompile_headers(lib PUBLIC "pch.h") .   everything acted as expected.